# Concatenate int variable from for loop with string

Tags: powershell, concatenation

I'm passing in possibly four file names: FileName1, FileName2, FileName3, FileName4.

Some may be empty, some not. Because of this I need to check if they are  empty before using them. So instead of using four if statements I thought I would just loop through them. How I wanted to do that was like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    $FileName = $FileName + $i
    Write-Host $FileName
}
```

So I can get Filename1, FileName2, FileName3, FileName4. Instead I get 1, 1 + 2, etc.

I've also tried `$FileName$i`, `$FileName"$($i)"`, `$FileName + "$($i)"`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

FileName1, FileName2, FileName3, FileName4 are variables that are passed to the script. They could be `FileName1="Budget2018.xlsx"`, `FileName2="MonthlyExpenses.xlx"`, `FileName3=""`, `FileName4=""`. Or all four variables can contain values ... or just FileName1 can contain a value, etc.

I need to check if they are empty before I continue on processing them. So rather than use 4 if statements to check if they are empty I thought I could loop through them referencing the variables as `$Filename$i` where `$i` would be the value 1 to 4. I'm trying to concatenate the two values together to represent the variables that are the parameters.

Comment: Do you have a list of filenames?  Of course it doesn't work in your current iteration because you just keep adding to the same variable and will end up with 'name1234'

Comment: Close-voting as "unclear what you want". Where are you passing in four names? What do you mean "check if they are empty" ? What does checking for an empty string have to do with adding a counter to a name in a loop?

Comment: `1..4 | % { "FileName$_" }` would be a better powershell-y way to generate four names, than a Java-style counting loop and write-host.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'd rather call that a `C-style` loop than give Java any credit ;)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler and you are still using a loop anyway.

Comment: What are those 4 filenames? 4 variables? 4 strings? An array? Parameters to a function or script? You're "passing in" what and how exactly?

Comment: @EBGreen yes, and? The point is "don't write java-in-python, write python", but for powershell.

Comment: Well, my point is that it is a scripting language. So whatever works is right until it isn't. Just a different viewpoint I guess.

Comment: `$v = Get-Variable "FileName$i"` should do what you're asking. However, my advice would be: don't do that. Why do you think you need 4 individual numbered variables instead of just using an array?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want then this should do it:

```
For($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++){
        $FileName = 'FileName{0}' -f $i
        Write-Host $FileName
}
```

If you want to define the root portion of the name as a variable then:

```
$root = 'FileName'
For($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++){
        $FileName = '{0}{1}' -f $root,$i
        Write-Host $FileName
}
```

Ok, so based on the most recent edit, here is a way to do what I now think you want:

```
1..4 | %{(ls variable:\$("FileName$_")).value}
```

Comment: At the end, you only end up with one variable... This is equivalent to writing `$FileName += '4'`; just with an unnecessary loop

Comment: Oh, I assumed that there would be processing in the loop block and the $fileName was only used in the loop.

Comment: If you review my edit I'm trying to get it so that Write-Host $FileName would be Budget2018.xlsx, then MonthlyExpenses.xlx, then "" and finally "" as it loops through.

Comment: Holy smokes. That's not like what I read your question to be at all.

Answer (score 1):

This produces FileName1, FileName2 etc, but I'm not sure how that squares with "I'm passing in four possible filenames", as there's no list in your script.

```
For($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++){

        $FileName = "FileName$i"
        Write-Host $FileName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single filename, and you want a list created based off that, you can do something like this:

```
$FileName = 'test'
$FileList = for ($i = 1; $i -le 4; $i++) { "$FileName$i" }
$FileList
# => test1
# => test2
# => test3
# => test4
```

But I suspect you have a list of files given your question had "check if null/empty" mentioned in it.

Comment: Hi, I get 1 2 3 4. I've added more info to my original question